# Combine two different cumulative queries

Tags: mysql

I have two queries... first to get cumulative License_Fee for each month, second to get unique cumulative Event_Combined for each month. Both from the same table.  How can I combine them into one query?

The results table should show a table with the columns:

Month | Gross | Gross_Cumulative | Event_Cumulative | License_Fee_Per_Event

The last column is (Gross_Cumulative/Event_Cumulative)

First:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT(Royalty_Month) as Month, 
SUM(License_Fee) OVER(ORDER BY Royalty_Month) as Gross_Cumulative 
FROM Agency
```

Second:

```
WITH ecu AS (
  SELECT Event_Combined, 
  MIN(Royalty_Month) Royalty_Month
  FROM Agency
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT(ecu.Royalty_Month) as Month,
COUNT(Event_Combined) OVER (ORDER BY ecu.Royalty_Month) Event_Cumulative_Count 
FROM ecu
```

UPDATE:  I rewrote the first query but stuck on how to combine them.

Comment: Rewrite 1st query, eliminate UDV usage and apply window version of SUM() function. Convert each query to CTE and combine their outputs in outer query.

Comment: @Akina rewrote the first query but dont know how to combine them.